# Python Tornado don't load images from html

Tags: python, tornado

I have a html page that when loaded from firefox it works, but when it is send from tornado server it don't show the images.
My tornado server:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class mainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('./prop.html')
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", mainHandler)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

my prop.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>Title</title>
<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./fig1.jpg" />
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much.
The code below gave me the result expected

```
<img src="/static/fig1.jpg" />
```

but the

gave me a following error:

```
Exception: You must define the 'static_path' setting in your application to use static_url
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 2.52ms
```

How do I set this settings?

Comment: Does the below answer not address how to set the StaticFileHandler path? Otherwise, that `Application` object accepts a dictionary of `settings`, which is where you pass that value. http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=static_path#application-configuration

Answer (score 2):

Tornado doesn't treat images specially.

`/fig1.jpg` is a resource and since you haven't defined a handler for it, Tornado will not generate a response. For production, you should be using a webserver better optimized for serving static files, like nginx. For development, however, you can tell Tornado to serve static files like so:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", mainHandler),
    (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {
        "path": "/your/static/folder"
    }),
])
```

You can then update your HTML:

```
<img src="/static/fig1.jpg" />
```

Or better yet:

```
<img src="{{ static_url("fig1.jpg") }}" />
```